# Shiny R and V lookup

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame called `UP`. I am calling the table in my Shiny Dashboard.

The data frame `UP` is as below. I am looking for a Vlook type in R. For example, when I select `HCV` in `selectInput` dialogue box, I should get in server.r

Med = 2.30
std = 1.80

```
UP   
 Application                      Median     `Std Deviation`
    1 LCV (Ex . Tata Ace)          2.04           0.800
    2 Passanger Car _ UV Segment   11.2            3.35 
    3 Passanger Car_ Mini          11.4            6.10 
    4 HCV                          2.30            1.80

 usagepat = setNames(UP$Application, nm = UP$Application)

 shinyUI(
        dashboardPage(
       box(selectInput(inputId = "usepat", choices = usagepat, label = "Application", selected = FALSE), width = 5)
          )))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code for this. You can modify it as per your needs but it gives output similar to VLookup:

```
df <- read.csv(path to raw data file)

ui <- fluidPage(

(selectInput(inputId = "usepat", label = "Application", choices = df$Application)),

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
  )))

server <- function(input, output) {

myData <- reactive({
req(input$usepat)
res <- df[which(df$Application == input$usepat),]
#return results
res
})
  output$tbTable <- renderTable(myData())}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```